# Why am I getting "invalid max count" from grep in an alias?

Tags: bash, grep, alias

So the idea is to create an alias that will search my alias's for me. I have quite a few.

```
dude@gnarleybox:~$ grep alg .bash_aliases.sh
alias alg='alias | grep '
dude@gnarleybox:~$ alias | grep alg
alias alg='alias | grep '
dude@gnarleybox:~$ alg gd
grep: invalid max count
dude@gnarleybox:~$
```

Huh? Like grep is getting two many parameters? How is that possible? Note that I've also tried it without the space on the end:

```
alias alg='alias | grep'
```

You should just be able to type:

```
 alg gd
```

...and get the alias I use to fuse mount GoogleDocs.

Comment: You definitely don't want the space at the end. If the alias ends with a space, it will cause `gd` to be alias expanded, which is probably why you get the invalid max count error. What happens without the space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the blank at the end of the alias definition (as suggested by rici) and your issue should be fixed.

But; in such cases as yours, where you have not only synonyms or abbreviations in your alias but also functional code with pipes, it's better to define a function instead of an alias.

Comment: Removing the space did not help.

Comment: Well you provided the solution (use a function) but terdon had a much better grip on the problem. Had to flip a coin.

Comment: @user447607 If this wasn't the solution why did you mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `gd` is also an alias and that expands to `-m` and something. To illustrate:

```
$ alias alg='alias | grep '
$ alias gd='-m foo'
$ alg gd
grep: invalid max count
```

The error message you show is what `grep` prints when it is given the `-m` (max count) option and a non-numerical argument. If you run `alias | grep gd`, I bet you'll see it matches something like what I've shown above.

As explained in `man bash`:

> If the last character of the alias value is a space or tab character, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

So, removing the space from the `alg` alias should also fix it.

Also, are you sure that `~/.bash_aliases.sh` is even being read? The [default file name](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html) is `~/.bash_aliases` with no extension. Unless you are explicitly sourcing `~/.bash_aliases.sh` it will be ignored.

Comment: Removing the space did not help.

Comment: OK that makes sense.  If you grep for an alias in an alias your second alias is expanded also.  Perhaps I need to escape it or something?